# What does -c mean as an argument to bash?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

```
  docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash -c "while true; do echo hello world;done"

  docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash "while true; do echo hello world; done"
```

I tried both.

In case 2, the container stopped immediately. So `docker ps` returns nothing. And `docker ps -a` returns just itself.

In case 1, `docker ps` lists the container. It is not stopped.

So what does -c flag do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the `bash` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> bash interprets the following options when it is invoked:
>
> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Without the `-c`, the `"while true..."` string is taken to be a filename for `bash` to open.

Answer (score 5):

The `-c` flag tells Bash that the next argument is a string of commands to run instead of the filename of a script. In the first case, Bash executes the next argument after `-c`. In the second case, where the `-c` flag isn't passed, Bash tries to run a script called `while true; do echo hello world; done` but can't find that script, so it quits.

From [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **-c** *string*
>
> If the **-c** option is present, then commands are read from *string*.  If there are arguments after the *string*, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with **$0**.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation(`docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash -c "while true; do echo hello world;done"`),
you have run docker with the docker CMD with value:

```
/bin/bash -c "while true; do echo hello world;done"
```

`-c` is the argument for `/bin/bash`, not for `docker`.

you can run `/bin/bash -c "while true; do echo hello world;done"` outside docker to see what happened.

Comment: Since there is `while`-loop running in the container, the bash process won't exit, and you can see this in `docker ps`. In the other case, `/bin/bash "while true; do echo hello world; done"` exit quickly.